# Unable to bind kendo grid data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to bind the kendo grid , i am getting data till controller.Controller returns data, but cannot see those data in grid. Anything wrong with the following code?

```
<div class="panel">    
<div id="chstry" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="float:none; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        @using Pnc.cmgr.Claims.Domain.Models;
        @using Pnc.cmgr.Claims.Domain.Common;
        @using Pnc.cmgr.Models;
        @using System.Linq;
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CaseAuditTrailViewModel>()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto; height:auto; text-center;margin-right: 30px;margin-left: 30px; " })
.Name("Allchstry")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.CaseAuditTrailId).Title("CaseAuditTrailId").Locked(true);
    columns.Bound(o => o.TableName).Title("TableName");
    columns.Bound(o => o.UserId).Title("UserId");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Actions).Title("Actions");
    columns.Bound(o => o.OldData).Title("OldData");
    columns.Bound(o => o.NewData).Title("NewData");
    columns.Bound(o => o.TableIdValue).Title("TableIdValue");
})
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
{
})
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(false))
.Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
.Sortable()
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
                        .Refresh(true)
                        .PageSizes(true)
                        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(o => o.CaseAuditTrailId);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetchstryByClaimId", "Claims", new { ClaimId = Model.Claim.ClaimId }))            
        .Events(events => { events.Sync("sync_handler"); }
        )
        )
        .Events(events => events            
        .DataBound("onDataBound")
        )
        )

        <script>
            function sync_handler(e) {
                this.read();
            }                       

        </script>            
    </div>

</div>
```

Following is the controller code and i am getting return data :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetchstryByClaimId([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Guid ClaimId)
        {
            var chstry = await _chstryProxy.GetchstryByClaimId(ClaimId);
            var gridData = new List<CaseAuditTrailViewModel>();
            Parallel.ForEach(chstry, (x) =>
            {
                gridData.Add(
                    new CaseAuditTrailViewModel
                    {                        
                        CaseAuditTrailId = x.CaseAuditTrailId,
                        Actions = x.Actions,
                        NewData = x.NewData,
                        OldData = x.OldData,
                        TableIdValue = x.TableIdValue,
                        TableName = x.TableName,
                        UpdateDate = x.UpdateDate,
                        UserId = x.UserId                          
                    });

            });
            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = gridData, 
                Total = gridData.Count()
            };

            //return new JsonResult { Data = result };
            return Json(result);
        }
```

Also, please let me know anything wrong the above approach of pulling data, view model binding is no where in the scene, do we have better approach to bind to process data faster?

Comment: Please show you controllers code that should provides data to your grid

Comment: Updated the code in question, i am getting return json data

Comment: I am getting around 1700 rows in the return json object ..is that a issue?

Comment: issue is with the data column , either missing , or have a format issue

Comment: have u included `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`?

Comment: the same code is working with another viewmodel in another page, i think issue is only problem with view model or properties or formats

Comment: Can you set AutoBind(true) for the grid ?